# Converting JSON to NDJSON with Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to convert a text file that has an array of json objects to an NDJSON formatted file for another team to consume.

I've almost got it, except for one problem. I have an array of objects nested inside the JSON (which then has nested arrays and objects inside of it, the structure gets pretty complex, I'll include a sample below) and for whatever reason, when I use ConvertFrom-JSON it drops this nested array and in my output, I end up with a blank string for that key, instead of the nested array object. I tried using the -Depth flag but when I do that my output file ends up blank, which doesn't make a ton of sense to me. I don't have a whole lot of experience with powershell, so I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong here.

Code:

```
$JSONSourceFile = Get-Content -Path "input/sample.json" | ConvertFrom-JSON
$NDJSONTargetFile = "output/sample.json"
New-Item $NDJSONTargetFile -ItemType file
for ( $i = 0 ; $i -lt $JSONSourceFile.Length ; $i++) {
  $item = $JSONSourceFile.item($i)
  $row = ($item | ConvertTo-JSON -Compress)
  Add-Content $NDJSONTargetFile $row
}
```

Input File:

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "TransactionDttm": "2021-02-22T15:45:00:00.000-05:00",
    "Array1": [
        {
            "UserID": "ak2354",
            "Preferences": [
                {
                    "CagegoryID": "01",
                    "CategoryName": "Reminder",
                    "Channels": [
                        {
                            "ChannelID": "1",
                            "ChannelName": "Email",
                            "Preference": "Y"
                        },
                        {
                            "ChannelID": "2",
                            "ChannelName": "Text",
                            "Preference": "N"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "TransactionDttm": "2021-02-22T15:45:00:00.000-05:00",
    "Array1": [
        {
            "UserID": "ak1234",
            "Preferences": [
                {
                    "CagegoryID": "01",
                    "CategoryName": "Reminder",
                    "Channels": [
                        {
                            "ChannelID": "1",
                            "ChannelName": "Email",
                            "Preference": "Y"
                        },
                        {
                            "ChannelID": "2",
                            "ChannelName": "Text",
                            "Preference": "Y"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "TransactionDttm": "2021-02-22T15:45:00:00.000-05:00",
    "Array1": [
        {
            "UserID": "ak5678",
            "Preferences": [
                {
                    "CagegoryID": "01",
                    "CategoryName": "Reminder",
                    "Channels": [
                        {
                            "ChannelID": "1",
                            "ChannelName": "Email",
                            "Preference": "N"
                        },
                        {
                            "ChannelID": "2",
                            "ChannelName": "Text",
                            "Preference": "N"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

And then when I convert it to the output, this is what I get:

```
{"id":"1","TransactionDttm":"2021-02-22T15:45:00:00.000-05:00","Array1":[{"UserID":"ak2354","Preferences":""}]}
{"id":"2","TransactionDttm":"2021-02-22T15:45:00:00.000-05:00","Array1":[{"UserID":"ak1234","Preferences":""}]}
{"id":"3","TransactionDttm":"2021-02-22T15:45:00:00.000-05:00","Array1":[{"UserID":"ak5678","Preferences":""}]}
```

Comment: It may not be able to show it all in that view, but it should be contained within. On my screen it shows `Preferences=System.Object[]` but I can drill into it and see the properties. Can you run the following tests?

Comment: Test 1
`$JSONSourceFile = Get-Content -Path "input/sample.json" | ConvertFrom-JSON

$JSONSourceFile | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20`
You should see all the same data.

Comment: Test 2: `$JSONSourceFile = Get-Content -Path "input/sample.json" | ConvertFrom-JSON

$JSONSourceFile.array1.preferences`
You should see all the data for categoryID, CategoryName, and Channels

Comment: Test 1 gave me nothing in the console (I also had to remove the second $JSONSourceFile to get it to parse). HOWEVER! I Added -Depth 20 to my ConvertTo-Json command and that did it, I was adding -Depth to my ConvertFrom-JSON command, this was the ticket!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Doug Maurer I figured it out, I was adding `-Depth` to my `ConvertFrom-Json` command when it should have been in my `ConvertTo-Json` command. This is the final script and what it gives me:

```
$JSONSourceFile = Get-Content -Path "input/sample.json" | ConvertFrom-JSON
$NDJSONTargetFile = "output/sample.json"
New-Item $NDJSONTargetFile -ItemType file
for ( $i = 0 ; $i -lt $JSONSourceFile.Length ; $i++) {
  $item = $JSONSourceFile.item($i)
  $row = ($item | ConvertTo-JSON -Compress -Depth 20)
  Add-Content $NDJSONTargetFile $row
}
```

and the output:

```
{"id":"1","TransactionDttm":"2021-02-22T15:45:00:00.000-05:00","Array1":[{"UserID":"ak2354","Preferences":[{"CagegoryID":"01","CategoryName":"Reminder","Channels":[{"ChannelID":"1","ChannelName":"Email","Preference":"Y"},{"ChannelID":"2","ChannelName":"Text","Preference":"N"}]}]}]}
{"id":"2","TransactionDttm":"2021-02-22T15:45:00:00.000-05:00","Array1":[{"UserID":"ak1234","Preferences":[{"CagegoryID":"01","CategoryName":"Reminder","Channels":[{"ChannelID":"1","ChannelName":"Email","Preference":"Y"},{"ChannelID":"2","ChannelName":"Text","Preference":"Y"}]}]}]}
{"id":"3","TransactionDttm":"2021-02-22T15:45:00:00.000-05:00","Array1":[{"UserID":"ak5678","Preferences":[{"CagegoryID":"01","CategoryName":"Reminder","Channels":[{"ChannelID":"1","ChannelName":"Email","Preference":"N"},{"ChannelID":"2","ChannelName":"Text","Preference":"N"}]}]}]}
```